# Python: Error saying "<function wordcount at 0x7f857957df28>"?

Tags: python

Alrighty, I've just completed my first uni unit in Python. For my final exam about 3 hours ago, I wrote the code below. I've come home to check it out to see if it works or not, and I'm getting an error which doesn't give any direction on how to fix it. The error says:

```
<function wordcount at 0x7f857957df28> How many words, characters and spaces is this?
```

The code I have written, which I'm hoping someone can point out my coding error, is here:

```
def wordcount(text):
    wc = (0,0,0)
    wc[1] = len(text)
    spaces = 0

    for x in range(text):
        if text[x] == " ":
            spaces += 1
    wc[2] = spaces
    wc[0] = spaces + 1

    return wc

print(wordcount,"How many words, characters and spaces is this?")
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], that would probably have told you that you're printing a function instead of calling it.

Comment: ``print(wordcount("How many words, characters and spaces is this?"))``

Comment: wordcount is a function() and you have to pass some text like `print(wordcount(How many words, characters and spaces is this?))` ... not a correct way to call function empty

Comment: `wc` is a tuple - tuple are immutable ... you can not `wc[1] = ...`

Comment: You can't assign things to tuples - you may want to change `wc = (0,0,0)` to `wc = [0,0,0]`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Then try it yourself. That's the error I'm getting, which is why I asked it.

Comment: You are printing the adress of your function: `print(wordcount, "whatever")` - you are not calling it. If you fix that you get the next error ... you call a fuction like this: `wordcount("Some text")`

Comment: I'm only using a tuple because it was part of the exam question. Maybe I should have put it as variables first then created a tuple at the end to return with?

Comment: `def wordcount(text): return  text.count(" "), len(text), text.count(" ")+1` would be a quite bad implementation (itertates the text twice to count spaces)

Comment: See if you can figure out what `print(print)` does. This is pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use working Code:

```
def wordcount(text):
    Characters   = sum(c.isalpha() for c in text)
    spaces  = sum(c.isspace() for c in text)
    wordslist = text.split()
    words = len(wordslist)
    return (words,Characters,spaces)

print(wordcount("How many words, characters and spaces is this?"))
```

Output:

```
(8, 37, 7)
```

Your Code after Corrections:

```
def wordcount(text):
    wc = [0,0,0]
    spaces = 0

    for x in text:
        if x == " ":
            spaces += 1
    wc[1] = len(text)-spaces
    wc[2] = spaces
    wc[0] = spaces + 1
    return wc

print(wordcount("How many words, characters and spaces is this?"))
```